# How to Animate Image In ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have listview and image view in the listview row,

I want to animate images in the list view on listview scroll, like when I scroll listview down image smoothly goes up and when I scroll listview up image smoothly goes down and also animate image in fling event smoothly.

can anyone suggest how can I do that and also not get performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with animation, if your image is a .png you can use a directory /anim with xml and differents instructions,  but i dont know if the animation you need is available.

check here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Set an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) on the list. In the onScroll callback, use the firstVisibleItem index and the visibleItemCount to iterate over each child view. For each child, get the position on screen (e.g. childView.getTop()), and set the image position accordingly.

Comment: i have tried this but on scroll only work when view is entirely scroll and new view is created.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the problem. What do you mean by 'entirely scroll'? 
In the onScroll callback you can iterate over all visible views. If I understand the original question correctly, that's where the image views are, right?